# PowerBI - Calculate the number of occurance of a value in a column using calculated field

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to calculate the number of times a value occurs in a column by using calculated field. Measure can do this a bit more easily, but measure limits my usage for creating other columns and the usages in the dashboards.

```
City

BOS

DTW

CLE

CLE

BOS

BOS

Expected Output:    

City   Total

BOS  3

CLE  2

DTW  1
```

Using the the option of Groupby in the query editor neglects the other columns which are on my data.

Comment: Do you want your output in a separate table or as another column in the same table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your output as its own table then you can do:

```
CityCount = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Cities[City], "Total", COUNT(Cities[City]))
```

If you want it as a calculated column:

```
Total = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Cities, Cities[City] = EARLIER(Cities[City])))
```

(Assuming your table name is `Cities`.)

Comment: This squares all of my results. My id 003 is in the table 5 times, but this count comes back as 25 and so on. I tried another solution and the same thing happens.
COUNTX (FILTER ( 'Giving Units Report', EARLIER ( 'Giving Units Report'[GiverID] ) = 'Giving Units Report'[GiverID] ),
    'Giving Units Report'[GiverID]
)

Comment: Never mind. I needed to choose that field in the visual and tell it not to summerize.

Comment: @rlphilli how to tell it to not summarize?